# JPA - EntityManagerFactory - Execução lenta

Tags: jpa, eclipse

Caros,

Estou brincando com persistências e algo estranho ocorre quando executo a partir do eclipse. O mesmo não ocorre quando executo no jar.

Alguém já passou por isso?
Eclipse Photon (4.8.0) + Maven + EntityManagerFactory + JPA

```
Set 14, 2018 2:06:37 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: XXX
    ...]
Set 14, 2018 2:06:37 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.16.Final}
Set 14, 2018 2:06:37 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Set 14, 2018 2:06:37 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Set 14, 2018 2:06:37 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Set 14, 2018 2:06:37 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Set 14, 2018 2:06:37 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] at URL [jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DBTeste]
Set 14, 2018 2:06:37 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=sa, password=****}
Set 14, 2018 2:06:37 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Set 14, 2018 2:06:37 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Set 14, 2018 2:35:48 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
Set 14, 2018 2:35:49 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@72ca7fc] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Set 14, 2018 2:35:51 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Conta
        (agencia, banco, numero, titular) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Observem o intervalo de tempo.

```
Set 14, 2018 2:06:37 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Set 14, 2018 2:35:48 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
```

Meu pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>XXX</name>
    <url>http://xxxx.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <description>API teste</description>
</project>
```

Comment: A execução usando JAR é feita da sua máquina também? Quanto tempo demora com o JAR? Tente aumentar o nível do log para DEBUG ou TRACE para ter mais informações.

Comment: Sim, executo na mesma máquina... Duvida! Estou procurando referências mas não encontrei uma forma de aumentar o log sem que seja pelo log4j. Teria outra maneira?

Comment: Implementei o log4j e para no mesmo ponto ... vou fazer um teste com mysql e posto os resultados..

Comment: Aparentemente por algum motivo que ainda não sei, através do eclipse não consigo ter acesso a rede. Mesmo o DB estando na  minha máquina, está havendo um bloqueio .... estou tentando contornar...

Comment: Propositalmente estou usando java 1.7 que por sua vez não está instalado na minha máquina, eu apenas  referencio no eclipse para copilar o projeto, já que estou usando o Eclipse Photon que nativamente usa java 1.8.

Quando mudo para java 1.8, consigo rodar a aplicação no eclipse ao voltar para java 1.7 fica pendurado a execução.

Mesmo baixando o firewall persiste o problema.